# Tracking my bike - How could a company offer a GPS location tracker with no recurrent service fee?

Tags: security, theft, technology

I want to add a tracker to my bicycle.

I’ve come across [this](https://domisk.com/products/mini-magnetic-car-gps-tracking-device-with-no-monthly-fee) and am wondering if it’s too good to be true? If not, how does it work, and why is this the only example I can find? What are folks’ thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Welcome and thanks for an interesting question. However, I know there's a security angle, but this is only tangentially related to bicycles. Perhaps https://superuser.com/ would be a better venue for this question?

Comment: In reality they would make money by selling more and more units and when people stop buying them they shut the company down and everyone's units would stop working.

Comment: This question has hit the HNQ and hopefully attracts interest from new users.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The description of that device is extremely confusing and actually nearly completely false.

1. The same device (GF-07) is widely available on the usual Chinese suspects (AliExpress, Temu, etc.) for a fraction of the price in your link.
2. [A video of a test of the device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ua70zvelYHI) (in French, but you can activate subtitles with auto-translate) tells us that:

   - The device indeed takes a SIM (not included) and an optional TF card to store audio recordings
   - You can dial into the phone number of the SIM to hear what happens around the device
   - You can send SMS to the device to control it:

     - start recording to TF
     - call you whenever there's noise around
     - send you a link to a map with the current location
   - location is very approximative, as it is basically just the location of the cell tower the device is connected to, and it does not use GPS (contrary to what the page you linked to says)
   - according to the provided documentation battery life is 12 days standby and 4 to 6 in use (not verified), but the documentation also gives completely unrelated data like video resolution, so another grain of salt is recommended.
3. [Another video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/CQ21nLFqpkU) (in english) confirms the same and more:

   - no GPS
   - no app, control by SMS
   - 400 mAh battery, lasts only a few days
   - magnet is very weak

#### Edit 25/01/2024

The same manufacturer has other models (GF-09, GF-21, GF-22...) with different characteristics.

The GF-21 model for instance is very similar (and barely more expensive, less than €10 at some places), and actually has a real GPS. [Here's a video showing its use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XONJ9Ae7FxA). Still uses the same mechanism (you send an SMS, it returns a link with the location). It supposedly combines GPS, Cell and Wi-Fi to get the best possible location. There's also an app, not sure how exactly it communicates with the device.

I would still expect the battery life to be quite short (days at best, not months).

Also it seems it's 2G-only rather than 3G or 4G, which would be an issue where 2G has been discontinued, though I haven't really looked much further, I may be wrong. Other models may have different modems.

#### More generally:

- Access to GPS data once you have a GPS receiver is free, it's just a broadcast from satellites, no subscription needed for that.
- What costs on an ongoing basis is getting the info between the device and you, and possibly things like actually storing the data so you can review it later
- These devices eliminate part of the issue by having you provide a SIM card
- They still need to operate at least a server which will convert the data to a Google Maps link, though that is quite lightweight. But if they stop getting revenue, they could stop that server, and you're left with a paperweight.
- I'm not sure how the app works and communicates with the device (SMS or data via a server) and where any data is stored (if any): in the app or on a server. Again, if a server is involved and they make no money selling the hardware (or not enough to support the servers), they can pull the plug at any time.
- GPS is power hungry and so is wireless communication. Given the size of the devices and thus of the batteries, lifetime can only be very short, though probably very variable depending on what you do exactly. But even in standby it's probably days at most.
- GPS needs to receive signals from several satellites, and much prefers being in the open (the signals are weak and the antenna is tiny). Many of the example scenarios will probably result in no GPS data at all (and then only rely on cell and/or Wi-Fi - the former is a lot less accurate, the latter is only available in places where there actually is Wi-Fi around, preferably several access points).
- Many of the cheaper wireless modems are 2G-only, and 2G is being phased out, so that restricts coverage.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I wonder how it would obtain its cell tower location info though.

Comment: @TylerDurden The wireless module reports the cell tower ID, and there are databases/APIs which can then give you the location from that.

Comment: If it worked properly this would actually be a nice product. At least here in Austria you can easily get a mobile phone contract without any fixed/monthly fees. You’d then only have to pay the price for a single SMS (~9 Euro cents) when requesting the last known GNSS location.

Comment: @Michael That one just doesn't have a GNSS receiver, but see my edit for another model from the same manufacturer which does. There are still other limitations compared to the overly optimistic description in OP's link, though.

Comment: @Michael No fees at all for having a network connection? That's neat! If you have a dynamo (or want to track a car), you can get [something](https://docs.valetron.com/wiki/products/valtrack-v4-vts-esp32-c3) like you want for $50 that will recharge itself. IP67. No affiliation and untested.

Comment: @Michael Be aware that plugging a device on the "permanent" circuit in a car can empty a car battery surprisingly quickly. One needs to be sure it is well optimised to use as little current as possible (devices which rely on an external source do to usually take much attention to that). Coming back from holiday to find your car won't start is not fun...

Comment: You don't need a server for the google maps link, the url format contains latitude and longitude and a zoom factor. (edit awaiting approval)

Comment: @ratchetfreak while you could link to Google Maps directly, that’s not what the devices here do.

Comment: Based on the screenshot this is the UK, where 3G is phased out in the very-very near future, not 2G. The latter will stay until at least 2030 based on recent plans, however 3G will be shut down this year by some providers

Comment: Also far cheaper on eBay.

Answer (score 14):

GPS is a free service, but the backhaul is likely cellular based on the ad-copy.

Despite the text saying "No additional accessories necessary!" it is likely you have to fit a cellular SIM card of your own - the second image shows a sim receiver socket inside.

[image]

Also in image 3 it says "dial sim card number..." also showing it needs a cellular sim.

[image]

I would expect this unit to be cheaply made and fall apart under vibrations, and to be completely not waterproof.  For the price, it may be worth trying, but don't expect a lot.

Comment: The 5th picture says that a working SIM card must be supplied by the client. In other words: the manufacturer doesn't charge a fee for using the device, but "additional fees may apply". I like the idea, but the text is deceiving (somehow a shame given that's a nice model). Claiming that the product can be used for life is also deceiving, as it relies on 4G and 2G, that only exist as long as carriers support them, not for life.

Comment: I've always wanted to "monitoring and and spy silently andscretly"

Comment: For 30 UKP it might be worth a go, but don't expect more than a few month's service.

Comment: The ad showcases external usage in car wheel arches or on pets but the product description doesn't mention any IP code/protection and an exposed USB port backs up the theory that this thing will be dead as a dodo on the first water ingress.

Comment: @DoNuT yep - and putting a cellular device inside a metal thing like a frame tube will limit its radio performance, which will drain down the battery faster.

Answer (score 1):

They are either about not to provide any service to be paid for or they will monetize on advertisments.

You should read the "... With No Monthly Fee" as "... With No Monthly Fee paid to us, but..."

As Criggie pointed out already, GPS service is free but all the work around is not. The app probably will rely on:

- Other free or pay-by-ad services like maps, tracking app etc.
- Generally paid services like your data connection, device data connectivity, etc.

There might be a case there will be a hitch where you will pay by your personal data. it can be worth trying but using different phone and different accounts from your "true" virtual you might be a good approach.

Comment: _"There might be a case there will be a hitch where you will pay by your personal data."_ This is possible, but I think unlikely. I suspect it just responds to an incoming SMS, blips the GPS, and responds by SMS. It _could_ also SMS someone else, but you'd be able to see that in your phone records.

Comment: @Michael Not sure its only SMS-based - there's some screenshots of software running plotting a location on a map.   So its doing "something"

Comment: @Michael separately, there's absolutely a market for "aggregated traffic data" or location+velocity of cars, which is sold between companies like Google and Here/nokia and so on, they use that data for "traffic density" layers on their maps.

Comment: @Criggie Too bad. A voice-and-SMS only device would have been interesting. If it needs data, I wouldn't get one in the first place. With the forthcoming SMS-to-satellite stuff, it could have been very neat. FWIW, you _can_ get private bring-your-own-SIM trackers, but they might be $200 USD.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the device could be shipped with pre-paid card that should last for expected service life, likely several years. The cost of this card can be simply included into the price. The cheapest options start from somewhat [$4 per month](https://digitalrepublic.ch/en/?gclid=CjwKCAiAzc2tBhA6EiwArv-i6c2hxzaYSPlm9ZiOMVAIiM6vVON6j3p4oP5tq9OXvR-xhLIzFwLhlBoCqmIQAvD_BwE), so this would be an extra $96 for two years. Not cheap but also not impossible.

However the price as specified seems too cheap for this approach. More likely the instructions just say "insert your SIM card" without much going into details, where and how one should get it.